# Why is good to use debugging while creating an app?

Tags: debugging

i'm starting "now" at this world with python and other languages and i always keep asking myself "What is debug for?" i searched and found a conclusion that it's just for find bugs and errors.

But it's just that? find an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its name indicates debugging serves for finding bugs within your code in order to correct them and "de" remove "bugs.
Basically when you debug you try to locate the position of the problem. So. instead of running the whole script at once. you indicate to the code where to stop in order for you to perform your analysis.
Debugging may seem unnecessary at small scale. But for big scripts a developer with low skills in debugging is considered not a developer